# CMakeLists project hierarchy proper organization?

Tags: c, makefile, cmake

I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly organize my CMake project in order for it to build successfully. My project structure looks like this:

```
projectname
- CMakeLists.txt
- lib
   '- driver
      '- driver.h
      '- driver.c
   '- CMakeLists.txt
- src
   '- main.c
```

In my `projectname` level `CMakeLists.txt` these are the relevant lines:

```
add_subdirectory(lib)

target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE driver)
target_sources(app PRIVATE src/main.c)
```

In the `lib` level `CMakeLists.txt` these are the relevant lines:

```
add_library(
    driver
    driver/driver.h
    driver/driver.c
)

target_include_directories(driver PUBLIC ${PROJECTNAME_PATH}/driver)
```

In my `main.c` I have `#include <lib/driver/driver.h>` and it's giving me the error `lib/driver/driver.h: No such file or directory`.

How can I reformat my CMake project so that the build works? Thank you.

Comment: Directory structure is fine. What is `PROJECTNAME_PATH`? If it is `projectname` then that needs to be `target_include_directories(driver PUBLIC ${PROJECTNAME_PATH}/lib/driver)` or better still just `target_include_directories(driver PUBLIC driver)`

Comment: @kaylum Yes it is `projectname`. I tried changing it to `target_include_directories(driver PUBLIC ${PROJECTNAME_PATH}/lib/driver)` but I still get the same error

Comment: Sorry, looks like your include in the C file is wrong too (or at least incompatible with the include paths used). Please show that. It should just be `#include "driver.h"` since you already have `driver` subdir in the include path.

Comment: @kaylum I tried that but same error.

Comment: Can't help further without full info. Please provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is interaction between the Cmake setup and the actual source code. So we need both. Specifically what does `max77818.h` look like and any other headers and source involved?

Comment: Ahh sorry I forgot to simplify the name of my files in the `#include` but it's changed now. `driver.h` is essentially empty with only a test function. All my files are very bare bones as I'm trying to set up the project correctly first.

Comment: "*I tried that but same error*". Coding is a precise task so we need precise info. There is no way the error is the same if you changed the code as it would at a minimum no longer have "lib/driver" in the error. Trying to help but its difficult without clear and complete info.

Comment: @kaylum If I do `#include "driver.h"` the error I get is `driver.h: No such file or directory`